# "No data received" with custom handler403 in django

Tags: django

When setting a simple handler403 for Django:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


class PermissionDeniedView(TemplateView):
    template_name = '403.html'


handler403 = PermissionDeniedView.as_view()


def my_view(request):
    raise PermissionDenied


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', my_view),
]
```

The browser does not receive any data (ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in chrome), and some errors appear on the log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 86, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 127, in finish_response
    for data in self.result:
  File "/home/foo/.virtualenvs/bar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 171, in __iter__
    raise ContentNotRenderedError('The response content must be '
ContentNotRenderedError: The response content must be rendered before it can be iterated over.
[20/May/2015 07:26:25]"GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 59
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 599, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/home/foo/.virtualenvs/bar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 102, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 655, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/home/foo/.virtualenvs/bar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 182, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 92, in run
    self.close()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 33, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Answer (score 1):

`TemplateView` returns a `TemplateResponse` instance with lazy content rendering by default, and is not suitable as is for `handler403`.

To force this view to render it's content, make sure `.render()` is called before returning the response:

```
class PermissionDeniedView(TemplateView):
    template_name = '403.html'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(PermissionDeniedView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        response.render()
        return response
```